# Writing unit test for this S3 function

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 function that is defined as follows:

```
def get_unprocessed_s3_object_list(s3_client, bucket: str) -> List[str]:
    paginator = s3_client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")
    page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)

    all_files = {}

    for page in page_iterator:
        if page["KeyCount"] > 0:
            for item in page["Contents"]:
                all_files[item["Key"]] = item["LastModified"]

    return sorted(all_files, key=lambda k: k[1])
```

Now, I was hoping to write a unit test for this and tried to use the stubber object from botocore to be able to test it. I tried something like:

```
def test_unprocessed_s3_objects():
    client = boto3.client("s3")
    stubber = Stubber(client)

    list_objects_v2_response = {
        "Contents": [
            {
                "Key": "sensor_1",
                "LastModified": "2021-11-30T12:58:14+00:00",
                "ETag": '"3a3c5ca43d2f01dba42314c1ca7e2237"',
                "Size": 1417,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            },
            {
                "Key": "sensor_2",
                "LastModified": "2021-11-30T12:58:05+00:00",
                "ETag": '"02bc99343bbdcbdefc9fe691b6f7deaa"',
                "Size": 1332,
                "StorageClass": "STANDARD",
            },
        ]
    }

    stubber.add_response("list_objects_v2", list_objects_v2_response)
    items = get_unprocessed_s3_object_list(client, "test")
    assert len(items) == 2
```

However, this comes back with `Access Denied with ListObjectsV2 ooperation`. Maybe this has to do with the bucket ID. I thought this would bypass the actual call.

Comment: Does it work if you add `stubber.activate()`? You may also want to look at moto: https://github.com/spulec/moto

Comment: Ah yes! That did work. I have other errors but this is sorted. Thanks. Would you mind writing it as an answer, so I can accept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling `stubber.add_response("list_objects_v2", list_objects_v2_response)`, you need to call `stubber.activate()` in order for the stubber to be used.